# abstract class in .h or .cpp file or both?

Tags: c++

Where should my abstract class be placed, in the .h or .cpp file or both? As there are no implementation details to be placed into the .cpp file?

From my understanding I would only require a .h file as all functions are virtual and if I do add a non-virtual function then I would require a .cpp file for the implementation of that non-virtual function.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong - the implementation can go in  the header  file.

Comment: Nothing in the C++ standard restricts you from putting everything (all classes, their declaration, definition and instantiating included) in a single file. The only thing that you must have (if you want to compile a library or an executable) is a source file with an entry point aka `main` function. The rest is left up to the developer. Of course putting an interface inside a source file with the intention of reusing it doesn't make much sense unless all the classes that implement it are there too. Inclusion of source files is in general not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description in the second paragraph is essentially correct; the fact that a class is abstract does not affect how you approach it. The usual approach is to put the class definition in a header file, and the implementation in a source file. The header file is used wherever the class is going to be used; it provides a description of the class. The source file gets compiled and linked; it provides the implementation details. If there are no implementation details there is no need for a source file.

Note that "abstract class" does **not** mean "class with no implementation". An abstract class has **at least** one pure virtual function. It does not mean that all virtual functions are pure, nor that the class has no non-virtual functions. And, conversely, a class that is not abstract might have no member functions, so no implementation file.